# Google Cloud SDK java.nio.file.InvalidPathException

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to connect backend class with the cloud 
This error because of the path is empty I searched a lot but didn't found article or similar question with my error

```
6:37:10 PM: Executing task 'appengineStart'...
Executing tasks: [appengineStart] in project C:\Users\Etch\Desktop\Gradle for android and java\FinalProject\backend
> Task :backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :backend:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :backend:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :backend:endpointsDiscoveryDocs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :backend:_zipDiscoveryDocs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :backend:war
> Task :backend:explodeWar
> Task :backend:assemble

> Task :backend:appengineStart FAILED
com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.PathResolver: exception thrown when searching for Google Cloud SDK
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\gcloud
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
```

**any article or links that would help please refer it**

Comment: How do you provide the path?

Comment: I don't know where to pass the path in backend if you know refer it